# Episode about a group who book passage on a space ship controlled by an AI, who turns out to be a human who can't leave his ship?

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification

I think that this is probably an episode of a show like The Outer Limits. From the 1990s or early 2000s. It could possibly be a made for TV movie.

A group of people from a planet without independent space travel book passage on a ship tp the next star system. I think that they were just traveling for trade or diplomatic reasons.

The ship is has no crew, and is controlled by an AI that starts to take a creepy interest in a female passenger. Watching her through the CCTV and so on.

At the end the AI reveals that it is really a human who was has lived his entire life in space. He has never left the ship, and now is unable to survive anywhere else as he can't live in normal gravity or be exposed to things like pollution.

Can you help to identify it.

Comment: Related, sort of: "Kendy" in Niven Pournelles Integral trees / smoke ring IS an AI but he is the unembodiment of a prior real person (memory says). || "Kendy for the state. Kendy for the state ...""

Comment: Almost certainly wrong (so just a comment), but this does have some similarities with the brain of a brain/brawn pair from Anne McCaffrey's "Ship who ... " series. Again, there are enough differences to make think this is not right, but anyone who is interested in this story might also try those.

Answer (score 22):

This sounds a lot like the George R.R. Martin story "[Nightflyers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49769)" which has been made into a couple of (disappointing) media versions.

- [1987 film version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightflyers_(film))
- [2018 Syfy series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightflyers_(TV_series))

It has the isolated guy running the spaceship (he has no immunity) who spies on the passengers, and is besotted with a female one. He has mother issues though.

Comment: That last sentence is doing a lot of heavy lifting!